# How to make sure a clojure variable is of the right Java type

Tags: java, clojure, apache-poi

java-code `XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(p);`
clojure-code `(def row (.getRow sheet p))`
How do we make sure that row is of type `XSSFRow` ?

Comment: I would like to see the title more descriptive; e.g. "How to make sure a clojure variable is of the right Java type". I could edit it myself, but I prefer to let the questioner decide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clojure is dynamically typed, so the type of a var/value is determined at runtime.

If you want to make sure a value is of a certain class, you could make the following assertion:

```
(assert (= (class row) XSSFRow))
```

Or, more concisely (thanks to opqdonut):

```
(assert (instance? XSSFRow row))
```

This does not check for exact class, but for any superclass:

```
(instance? Object row) ;=> true
```

Comment: Or more concisely `(assert (instance? XSSFRow row))`

Answer (score 3):

Notice that there is a way to specify type hints for the compiler using metadata. In some forms you can insert the following constructions:

```
(let [^String str-val (do-something)] ...)
(def ^double y)
(defn f [^int int-arg ^"[[I" 2d-int-array] ...)
```

note the `^type` expression. This is shorthand for specifying one element of metadata, that is, `:tag` key in metadata map.
Now the compiler can optimize the code, directly resolving calls to java methods instead of reflection now when it knows exact type of var.

There is an example on clojure.org: http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints . It suggests, and I think it is right, not to overuse type hints, since they just clutter the code and are generally not needed for adequate performance.

Comment: On the other hand, if your code is only going to work with an XSSFRow (i.e. will fail if passed something else), then I think the type hint is good for documentation purposes, and the fact that the compiler doesn't have to generate reflection code is a nice incidental bonus.